# Trouble mapping Django URLs

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've completed all of the sections of the Django tutorial and have started my own project now to practice. I am back at the beginning tutorial where [it talks about views/mapping urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/). I also am following [this tutorial for trying to display a table](https://www.etutorialspoint.com/index.php/251-how-to-get-data-from-mysql-in-django-view-with-models)

For whatever reason, I cannot figure out why when I try to hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/show/, it returns 404. I've been staring at this for the last hour and have been going back and forth between the tutorial and my code. I had to do things a little bit differently than the 2nd mentioned tutorial, mainly that they didn't talk about creating an app-level urls.py file. Everything up to this point has worked fine. The models.py file created the table within the MySQL database, as I can see it in the workbench.

My project structure is like this:

- mywebsite (project)
- displaydata (app)

Here is my project level urls.py file located in the mywebsite folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('displaydata/', include('displaydata.urls'))
]
```

Here is my app-level urls.py file located in the displaydata folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'displaydata'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.show, name='show')
]
```

Here is my displaydata views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Shipment

# Create your views here.

def show(request):
    shipments = Shipment.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(render(request,"show.html",{'shipment':shipments}))
```

Here is the show.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Django CRUD Operations</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Shipment ID</th>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>Destination City</th>
        <th>Destination State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ship in shipment %}  
      <tr>
        <td>{{ship.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.driver}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.destination_city}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.destination_state}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will hit the `show` view for the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/displaydata/`.

This the case because you include all the `displaydata` urls with the `displaydata/` prefix. In the url patterns of your `displaydata` app, there is one pattern: the empty string, so it will match this for the path `/dispaydata`.

If you want to access the view with `/show`, you can use an empty string as prefix in the project urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('displaydata.urls'))
]
```

and then for the `displaydata` urls work with:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'displaydata'

urlpatterns = [
    path('/show/', views.show, name='show')
]
```

If the template is located at `app_name/templates/app_name/show.html`, then you render the template with:

```
def show(request):
    shipments = Shipment.objects.all()
    return render(request,'app_name/show.html',{'shipment': shipments})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and ran into this issue: "/..show.html (Source does not exist)"

However, upon closer inspection it looks like it was looking for the html template one directory up from where it was. 

I originally had it in mywebsite/displaydata/templates/displaydata/show.html
But it wanted mywebsite/displaydata/templates/show.html

Do you know why the official django tutorial asks to nest it (and it worked during that tutorial) but in this instance it was looking one directory up? Is there anywhere I need to specify that?

Comment: @krisbkreeme: you can not visit a template, so `/..show.html` does not make much sense. You trigger views, that respond with a HTTP response, for that response, the view can render zero, one or multiple templates, but templates are thus more a tooling to generate a HTTP response.

Comment: @krisbkreeme: can you edit the question with the content of the template.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But then if I just take your advice of hitting localhost/displaydata, I get this error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /displaydata/. I then have to move it one directory up from where I originally put it, which is what my first comment was referring to. And now, if I do that, I get the HTML rendered but no data is being displayed. I think there is a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: @kriskreeme: where did you store the `show.html` template?

Comment: If this is located at `displaydata/templates/displaydata/show.html`, you should render with `render(request, 'displaydata/show.html', {'shipment':shipments})`.

Comment: I originally stored it in mywebsite/displaydata/templates/displaydata/show.html (following the guide from django's website)

But it seems that it was looking for the template one directory up, in the /templates/ folder

Comment: @krisbkreeme: indeed, so you access it with `'displaydata/show.html'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234087/discussion-between-krisbkreeme-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: I was able to add the show.html file to the original post. Let me know.

Comment: hold that thought, I was an idiot and forgot to actually insert anything into the table.